# Does adding new field to redux state during dispatch allowed?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
export const userReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
    case REGISTER_USER_REQUEST:
    case LOAD_USER_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS:
    case LOAD_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload,
      };

    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
      };
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case REGISTER_USER_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    case LOAD_USER_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    case LOGOUT_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Is it allowed to add next field to intial state in redux ?
and if allowed is it right to write code like this?

Is it allowed to add next field to intial state in redux ?
and if allowed is it right to write code like this?
Is it allowed to add next field to intial state in redux ?
and if allowed is it right to write code like this?
Is it allowed to add next field to intial state in redux ?
and if allowed is it right to write code like this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is not clear but I'll give some points based on the code you've shared.

if you return like this

```
return {
        loading: false,
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
};
```

it will only return this data and all the other data in the state would be lost. if you're intentionally doing that, that's fine. But if you need to keep those data you need do as follows,

```
return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
};
```

You need to spread the current state and pass it, This is one point I need to mention.

The other thing I'm not really clear about what you mean by `next field`, if you mean to add something rather than you've mentioned at the beginning yes it's fine we can do that but it's a best practice to define all the variables that you gonna use as your state, because otherwise it will be very hard to debug if your application does something unpredictable because the data you're assigning is initiated in runtime may cause some problems.

Therefore it's a good idea to make your initial state like this.

```
const initialState ={
        user: {},
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        error:false
}
```

and then pass this to your reducer like this.

```
export const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 .... other codes 
}
```